# WPF databinding during using the Arduino

Tags: c#, wpf, arduino

I am developing a application with C# and Arduino.I reading values from Arduino and set the value on the textbox.I want always read value from Arduino and set this on the interface.However this code doesn't working.
Shoul I run while statement in a different thread?

This is my code

```
     SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600);
        port.Open();
        while (true)
        {
            String s=port.ReadLine();
            txtValue.Text=s;

        }
        port.Close();

    }
```

I want show value which I read from Arduino to show in the textbox simultaneously.

Comment: In given code snippet you are **not** *reading values from Arduino*.

Comment: I corrected it but still doesn't work.Maybe because of while statement.I want show value in the textbox simultaneously

Comment: If given snippet is running in UI thread, then it will block it and you see no `txtValue` changes. You have to organize it differently.  Create and run `Task` (or `Thread`) in which you open com-port and start reading. When you want to update `txtValue` - [invoke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4016979/1997232) it. Don't forget to provide a safe mechanism to stop task (**do not** abort `Thread`!) and close com-port, to example, set some variable when form is closed, this variable is constantly checked inside your `while` to `break` it.

Comment: should I call thread in the constructor or different place?

Comment: I'd highly recommend using the MVVM pattern, it will make your life much easier.  With MVVM you won't have to move most code onto the UI thread for updating your display.

Comment: Is there good resource on the MVVM pattern.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code to start (put it in constructor, window `Loaded` or button click event):

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    _stop = false; // define as private field of window class
    var port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600);
    port.Open();
    while (!_stop)
    {
        var s=port.ReadLine();
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => txtValue.Text = s); // InvokeAsync?
    }
    port.Close();
});
```

This is code to stop (put it into window `Closing` event):

```
_stop = true;
```

This doesn't uses any bindings, but should give you an idea of how to organize port operation (with or without bindings).

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the arduino side, but if you are using .net 4.0 or 4.5 you could do something like below:

```
Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    while (true)
    {
        String s=port.ReadLine();
        txtValue.Text=s;

    }

 });
```

as mentioned by Sinatr be sure to have a way to stop execution. You could do this by setting a vairable instead of using "true". As for where to put the code it is really dependent on what your final program will be.

Answer (score 1):

With [MVVM Light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm) and [SolidSoils4Arduino](https://github.com/SolidSoils/Arduino) you should be able to quickly create an observable binding with Arduino serial messages.

Here is a basic viewmodel class:

```
public class MainViewModel : GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase, IObserver<string>
{
    #region Fields

    private string _lastSerialMessageReceived;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _serialMessages = new ObservableCollection<string>(); 

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var connection = new Solid.Arduino.SerialConnection("COM3", Solid.Arduino.SerialBaudRate.Bps_115200);
        var session = new Solid.Arduino.ArduinoSession(connection);
        session.CreateReceivedStringMonitor().Subscribe(this);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Interface

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnNext(string value)
    {
        _serialMessages.Add(value);
        LastSerialMessageReceived = value;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> SerialMessages
    {
        get { return _serialMessages; }
    }

    public string LastSerialMessageReceived
    {
        get { return _lastSerialMessageReceived; }
        private set { Set(() => LastSerialMessageReceived, ref _lastSerialMessageReceived, value); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You can bind your textbox to property LastSerialMessageReceived. Property SerialMessages could be bound to a listbox.